# Detect certain characters and if not a consequence

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

How can I program in Arduino Uno a `serial.available` that will detect some chars that aren't supposed to belong in a list of options, like this:

```
void lerRespostaUtilizador(){
  if(Serial.available('s' && 'v' && 'r'){
    Serial.println("Podes visualizar: (s)inais de controlo, (v)ariaveis do sistema e conteudo de (r)egistos.")
  }
  switch(Serial.read()){
    case 's': // Mostrar sinais de controlo
      mostrarSinais();
      Serial.println("Podes visualizar ainda: (v)ariaveis do sistema e conteudo de (r)egistos.");
      Serial.println("");
      break;
    case 'v': // Mostrar variáveis do sistema
      mostrarVariaveis();
      Serial.println("Podes visualizar ainda: (s)inais de controlo e conteudo de (r)egistos.");
      Serial.println("");
      break;
    case 'r': // Mostrar conteúdo de registos
      mostrarRegistos();
      Serial.println("Podes visualizar ainda: (s)inais de controlo e (v)ariaveis do sistema.");
      Serial.println("");
      break;
    }
}
```

What I want is if the user inserts some chars that aren't 's', 'v' or 'r', a message will appear saying what they can insert to obtain certain results.

Comment: Check this `Serial.available('s' && 'v' && 'r')`. I can guess what you think it means but it does not.

Comment: How can I correct it then?

Comment: Simply wait for something to read, read the character, and add a default switch section case that catches illegal characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite that as something like this:

```
void lerRespostaUtilizador(){
  while (!Serial.available());
  switch(Serial.read()){
    case 's': // Mostrar sinais de controlo
      mostrarSinais();
      break;
    case 'v': // Mostrar variáveis do sistema
      mostrarVariaveis();
      break;
    case 'r': // Mostrar conteúdo de registos
      mostrarRegistos();
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println(F("Podes visualizar: (s)inais de controlo, (v)ariaveis do sistema e conteudo de (r)egistos."));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeap, that works perfectly!
But can you explain me how the while works and how is it connected to the default option?